# AC New Leaf: non-mayor player specifics

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In *Animal Crossing: New Leaf* for the Nintendo 3DS (cartridge version), you can create multiple save slots. I have been trying to find more information on what this entails.

Facts I've found online:

- Only one town per cartridge
- The first save slot is the Mayor and other save slots are separate villagers
- These non-Mayor players (which I'll call NMPs) each get their own house, bells, and inventory, and can do most things in the game. However, they can't perform mayoral duties (e.g. ordinances, public works projects)
- NMPs generally unlock features such as the island separately from the Mayor.

What I can't find are other specifics on gameplay for the non-Mayor players, particularly regarding once-a-day activities.

1. In the morning, the Mayor goes through the town, shakes every tree, hits every rock, and waters every flower. Are the trees, rocks, and flowers unavailable for the NMP later in the day since the Mayor already tended to them, or are trees/rocks/flowers tracked separately for the NMP?
2. In the morning, the Mayor buys all of the limited-stock items from Nookling Junction or the campground. Will there be nothing available for an NMP to buy later in the day, or do they see separate stock?
3. Can the NMP invite other players from the internet or local wireless?
4. If the mayor unlocks TT Mart (upgraded version of Nookling Junction), do NMPs see TT Mart or do they have to unlock it separately?
5. Once the NMPs have unlocked the island, do they share the same island as the Mayor? For example, the Mayor plants some roses on his island; does the NMP see the same roses? If the NMP cuts down a tree on the island, is it gone from the Mayor's island as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now having had an opportunity to test it myself, I can answer most of the questions:

1. Tree/rocks/flowers/fossils/etc are all shared, meaning that if one player takes care of those tasks, they are unavailable for other players later in the day. However, each player has their own daily and weekly MEOW Coupon initiatives.
2. The store stock is shared; if one player buys a limited-stock item, it will be unavailable to other players later in the day.
3. It looks like normal multiplayer functionality is available to non-mayor players
4. When Nookling Junction is upgraded to TT Mart, the upgraded version is fully available for all players, including the catalog (but each player has their own catalog).

An additional note: the museum is shared, so you can't donate something that has already been donated - but you can just sell it to Re-tail.